# HttpContext.Current is null only when debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I've recently started working on an established MVC application using VS2013.
For some reason, HttpContext.Current is null only when running in debug mode - If I remove breakpoints it seems to work, but I don't understand why this should happen running locally.

This isnt just on Chrome - so far, it also happens when debugging through IE11.

If it helps, the solution is using IIS Express as dev web server.

```
public UserSessionData GetSession()
{ 
    HttpSessionStateBase httpSession = new HttpSessionStateWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Session);
}
```

Comment: You show no code, giving us very little to work with.

Comment: If you could provide more information as to exactly where in the application's pipeline you are trying to debug the `HttpContext` object then we would better be able help you.

Comment: Thing is, I'm not trying to debug the HttpContext, this just gets thrown when this method is called:
        public UserSessionData GetSession()
        {
            HttpSessionStateBase httpSession = new HttpSessionStateWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Session);

Comment: it does look app fault related now, as opposed to a generic issue when debugging.

Comment: Please edit your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not keep the Debugger in this line -- > `HttpSessionStateBase httpSession = new HttpSessionStateWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Session);`
 After executing this line, then only the value will be assigned to this variable `httpSession`.

So, Keep the Debugger in this line --> `}`.  Then check the `httpSession` in QuickWatch or Mouse Hover.

The value should be there. No its not a Generic Issue. Its Human Error / Mistake.

Comment: correct. this is symptomatic of another problem on the fault list for this app. My bad: I'm new to VS2013, and new to this particular app! :-p

Comment: @JimFR Its ok. +1 for your try and Welcome to stack overflow.

Comment: @ShaunWilson The problem is, user doesn't know how to debug the code part properly. Before assigning `httpSession` value (either it can be null or it can hold some value). He is trying to check the `httpSession` value. So it's his mistake. There will be nothing, before assignment. But still the same code works when he didn't debug. So it was my guess. Since he is new to MVC. **He is not facing any Null Reference Exception**. The posted answer solves the problem of his question. Hence he accepted it. :)